# How do I preserve null values in populated array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have mongoose document like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("56a5ddb76c9248f30746a425"),
    people: [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        ObjectId("56a5dd816c9248f30746a420"),
        null,
        null,
        ObjectId("56a5ddae6c9248f30746a424"),
        ObjectId("56a5dd6c6c9248f30746a41e"),
        ObjectId("56a4d6652cc5cd631b6f3255"),
        ObjectId("56a5ddb76c9248f30746a425"),
        null
    ]
}
```

When I do `doc.populate("people")`, the people array contains only five elements, but I need to preserve those nulls. How do I do this?

Comment: Any reason why you want to?

Comment: Array represents binary tree, so I need to preserve indexes